# Заменить оглавление многоуровневным списком с помощью чистого JS

Tags: javascript

Я написал сперва такой скрипт

```
function htoul(el)
{
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName(el), // Create a collection of H1 elements
ul = document.createElement('ul'), // Create a new UL element
parent = h1[0].parentNode, // Store the parent node of the first H1
n, len, li; 
// Declare some variables to use later
for (n = 0, len = h1.length; n < len; n++) { // Iterate through H1 elements
li = document.createElement('li'); // Create a new LI element
li.innerHTML = h1[0].innerHTML;
h1[0].parentElement.removeChild(h1[0]); // Move a H1 to LI (Live collection, 0 instead of n as index)
// Or switch the line above to the next two lines, if you want to remove the H1 and list the content only
// li.innerHTML = h1[0].innerHTML;
// h1[0].parentElement.removeChild(h1[0]);// If you want to preserve H1s, remove this line
ul.appendChild(li); // Append the newly-created LI to the UL
}
parent.appendChild(ul); 
return ul; 
}

function lab() {
ul = htoul('h1');
ul1 = htoul('h2');
ul2 = htoul('h3');

ul.appendChild(ul1);
ul1.appendChild(ul2);
}
```

Мне не совсем понятно, как его следует изменить таким образом, чтобы соблюдалась иерархия заголовков.

```
<h1>Глава 1. Измеримость и меры</h1>
<h2>&sect; 1. Сигма-алгебры и измеримые отображения в метрических пространствах</h2>
<h3>1. Измериые пространства и отображения, борелевская сигма-алгебра</h3>
<h3>2. Сигма-алгебры, порождённые семействами отображений</h3>
<h3>3. Сигма-алгебры в произведении пространств</h3>
<h3>4. Структура измеримых отображений</h3>
<h3>5. Упражнения</h3>
<h2>&sect; 2. Сигма-алгебры в банаховых пространствах</h2>
<h3>1. Измериые векторные пространства</h3>
<h3>2. Соотношения между различными сигма-алгебрами</h3>
<h3>3. Вспомогательные результаты и контрпримеры</h3>
<h3>4. Упражнения</h3>
<h2>&sect; 3. Вероятностные меры в топологических пространствах</h2>
<h3>1. Некоторые сведения из общей теории меры</h3>
<h3>2. Регулярные, тау-гладкие и радоновы меры</h3>
<h3>3. Носитель меры</h3>
<h3>4. Структура измеримых отображений</h3>
<h3>5. Упражнения</h3>

<h1>Введение в пространство Соболева</h1>
<h2>Обобщённая производная</h2>
<h3>Мультииндекс</h3>
```

Вопрос: как сделать нужные заголовки с большими номерами детьми заголовков с меньшими номерами с сохранением такой же иерархии?

Comment: Вы, наверное, опечатались - "заголовки с большими номерами детьми заголовков с меньшими номерами". Это же как вывернутый наизнанку список будет.

Comment: Я в том смысле, что h2 должен быть ребёнком h1, h3 - h2, и т. д.

Comment: надо сразу по всем в цикле бежать. сравнивать предыдущий тэг с текущим.

Comment: Можете подсказать, как это сделать? Я пытался через appendchild, но у меня не работало

Comment: у вас функция три раза вызывается, а надо один  раз. подсказка -

    var hs=['H1','H2','H3','H4'];
    //...
    var n=hs.indexOf(element.tagName);

Answer (score 1):

http://pastebin.com/A769uU9s

В Chromium рабоатет. Почти как нужно.